# After querying RPM and fuel, OBDII is lighting all my dashboard lights

Tags: obd-ii, warning-light, dashboard

I'm using OBDII and after querying the rpm and the fuel, all the light in my dash board is lighting.  How do I need to query the car?

Why might this have happened?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance and Repair! Sounds like something's not too happy but we haven't got much to work on - any chance you can tell us the make and model of the car? The details of the OBD-II reader you are using would also be a huge help.

Comment: I'm using my own develop OBD and I HAVE PROBLEMS WITH CITROEN C1